# Saving model with has_many association fails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to save an object to the database and create the `has_many` associations, but it fails validation. I am currently on Rails 5.2 using Postgres.

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :routings,     dependent: :destroy
  has_many :work_centers, through: :routings
  validates :number, presence: true, 
                     length: { maximum: 255 },
                     uniqueness: true
  ...
end
```

**routing.rb**

```
class Routing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :work_center
  validates :item_id, presence: true
  validates :work_center_id, presence: true
  ...
end
```

**work_center.rb**

```
class WorkCenter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :routings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items,    through: :routings
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, 
                   uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :sequence, presence: true,
                       uniqueness: true
end
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(item_params)
  if @item.save
    ...
  end
end

private
  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:job_id, :number, :product_type, work_center_ids: [])
  end
```

When I try to create a new `Item` in rails console it fails with a validation error:

```
>   Item.create!(job_id: 58, number: "6872-ryan1", work_center_ids: [3,4])
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Routings is invalid
```

However, if I create the `Item` first and then add the `Routings` it succeeds:

```
>   i = Item.create!(job_id: 58, number: "6872-ryan1")
 => #<Item id: 583, number: "6872-ryan1", product_type: nil, job_id: 58, created_at: "2019-01-10 14:28:16", updated_at: "2019-01-10 14:28:16">
>   i.work_center_ids = [3,4]
 => [3, 4]
```

I tried adding `inverse_of:` to the models:

**updated item.rb**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :routings,     dependent: :destroy
  has_many :work_centers, through: :routings, inverse_of: :item
  ...
end
```

**updated work_center.rb**

```
class WorkCenter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :routings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items,    through: :routings, inverse_of: :work_center
end
```

but now I get a different error:

```
> Item.create!(job_id: 58, number: "6872-ryan2", work_center_ids: [3])
ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the inverse association for work_centers (:item in WorkCenter)
```

**Edited to show validations in models**

Comment: Do you have any validation in Item or Routing models?

Comment: I edited the question to include the existing validations in the models.

Comment: Try to remove item_id and work_center_id presence validation from Routing model. ROR validates `belons_to` automatically, starting from 5th version

Comment: Removing the validations from Routing allows me to create the Item and properly creates the new Routing, but now I can create Routings with blank `item_id` or `work_center_id`. This should not be allowed.

Comment: Do you have somewhere in config `belongs_to_required_by_default = false`? If yes, add `required: true` to belongs association. Or validate presence of item/work_center, not their ids - it is a correct way of `belongs_to` validation

Comment: Yes, `belongs_to_required_by_default = false` was in new_framework_defaults.rb from when I upgraded to Rails 5. I changed that to `true` and removed the validations from Routing, and it works now. If you make your comment into an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from 5th version of ROR, `belongs_to` association is validated by default, so you don't need these lines in the Routing model:

```
validates :item_id, presence: true
validates :work_center_id, presence: true
```

If after deletion you can create routing without item_id or work_center_id, please change `belongs_to_required_by_default = false` to `true` in config files.

In any case, you should validate presence of associated model, not its id. In former case you check if item (for example) with given id presents in the db, and in latter case you just check if `item_id` column has some value.